# Pandas how to calculate mean without current line

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Dataframe like `df = pd.Dataframe({'a':[1,2,3,4,5]})` I want to calculate mean without current line. For example: the first row should calculate as (2+3+4+5)/4. Is there any function can do this? Or it can only realized by for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about:

```
(df['a'].sum() - df['a']) / (df.shape[0] - 1)
```